# instanceof comparing two layouts returns unexpected result

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an app, where after I've dragged'n'dropped a shadow the receiving fragment is supposed to create a RelativeLayout, at the absolute coordinates where the shadow was dropped.

My problem lies in the LayoutParams of the dynamically created RelativeLayout and it not responding as a subclass of MarginLayoutParams.

According to this: [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams and should therefore be a subclass of the latter.

My Code:

```
RelativeLayout relLay = new RelativeLayout(getView().getContext());
    if(relLay.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams){
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) relLay.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(Math.round(coordX), Math.round(coordY), 0, 0);
        relLay.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        RelativeLayout fragView = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.RelativeStoryFaceFragment);
        relLay.addView(iView);
        fragView.addView(relLay);
    }
```

The *instanceof* operator returns *false*, where I would expect it to return *true*. *instanceof* is not supposed to be there, but I'm using it to avoid the ugly crashes that will result until I've figured out why my code is wrong.

I can't set the margins unless I cast but the cast will crash if the *instanceof* returns false.

I've tried to focus on the problematic code, but will gladly include further context if necessary.

I'm probably missing something embarassing, any takers?

Comment: "I'm using it to avoid the ugly crashes that will result until I've figured out why my code is wrong."  Why don't we just look at the crashes rather than trying to help you get a hack working?